Computing pullback of the one form $dx$
I have the following 1-form in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is $\omega=dx$, and it is given the map
$$\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to S^2 \setminus \lbrace N \rbrace  $$
$$ (x,y)\mapsto \left( \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+1}, \frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+1}, 1 - \frac{2}{x^2+y^2+1} \right) $$where N is the north, and I want to compute the pullback of $(\varphi^{-1})$, where I found that is given by
$$ \varphi^{-1}: S^2 \setminus \lbrace N \rbrace \to \mathbb{R}^2   $$
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto \left( \frac{x}{1-z}, \frac{y}{1-z} \right)  $$
but using the definition that Do Carmo gives I don't understand how to compute the pullback, where it is said that if we have $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ a differentiable map, then the pullback is:
$$ (f^{*}w)(p)(v_1, \ldots, v_k) = \omega(f(p))(df_p(v_1), \ldots, df_p(v_k)) $$
where $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $v_1, \ldots, v_k \in \mathbb{R}_{p}^{n}$, any help would be appreciated.

What is the problem ? Just apply the definiton swapping $f$ and $\phi^{-1}$.

Well, I don't know what the tangent vectors are.

Few hints: $\omega=dx$ does not depend on $f(p)$ and Do Carmo writes on the next page $$f^*(dy_i)=d(y_i\circ f),.$$ Also $k=1$ in your case. You will be astonished how simple it is. Probably better to write $$(u,v,w)\mapsto (x,y)=\left(\frac u{1-w},\frac v{1-w}\right),.$$ What is $dx$ in terms of $du,dv,dw,?$ Hint: basic calculus.

Thanks, don't know if I am correct, but may I need the chain rule?

Yes exactly. A lot of stuff in DG is nothing but the chain rule :)

I don't see chain rule here. I see only quotient rule. It's not clear what the original question was, however. You will get an expression involving $du$, $dv$, and $dw$, but these are $1$-forms on $\Bbb R^3$, and you need to understand that you are pulling them back (restricting) to $S^2-{N}$. Ordinarily you would compute the pullback in terms of some chart on $S^2-{N}$.

P.S. You might want to check out my YouTube lectures, particularly on differential forms. The link is in my profile.

I was watching precisely your Youtube Channel :D, and I have an approach.

I would recommend you to use two different sets of letters in order to distinguish the coordinates $(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2$ from $(u,v,w) \in S^2\setminus\{N\}$ clearly. Then, concretely, the pullback is a kind of fancy way to name what you would call informally a "change of coordinates", that is why nothing else than the chain rule hides ultimately behind Do Carmo's notation actually. In consequence, you can write straightforwardly :
$$
\mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{d}\left(\frac{u}{1-w}\right) = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-w} + \frac{u\,\mathrm{d}w}{(1-w)^2}
$$

And $dy=\frac{dv}{1-w}+\frac{v,dw}{(1-w)^2}$ but, as @Ted Shifrin pointed out, these are the pullbacks to $\mathbb R^3$ and not to a cotangent bundle of $\mathbb S^2-{N},.$

As discussed in the comments the pullbacks of $dx,dy$ on $\mathbb R^2$
by
$$
f(u,v,w)=\left(\frac u{1-w},\frac v{1-w}\right)
$$
to $\color{red}{\mathbb R^3}$ are simply given by
\begin{align}
f^*dx&=d(x\circ f)=d\left(\frac u{1-w}\right)=\frac{du}{1-w}+\frac{u\,dw}{(1-w)^2}\,,\\[2mm]
f^*dy&=d(y\circ f)=d\left(\frac v{1-w}\right)=\frac{dv}{1-w}+\frac{v\,dw}{(1-w)^2}\,,
\end{align}
where $du,dv,dw$ are the basis one-forms for $\mathbb R^3\,.$
The map $f$ can be seen as non injective map from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^2$ (which is what we just did) or from now on as bijective stereographic projection
from the unit sphere $S^2$ without its north pole to $\mathbb R^2\,:$
$$
f:S^2\setminus\{N\}\to\mathbb R^2\,.
$$
Then the formulas for the pullbacks depend on a chart for $S^2\,.$

The simplest chart here is $f$ itself. This leads to $f^*dx=dx,f^*dy=dy$ because the points of $S^2\setminus\{N\}$ are now those of $\mathbb R^2\,.$ In other words:
in these coordinates $f$ acts as the identity map.

Another popular local chart is the projection of the southern hemisphere to the $u,v$ plane:
$$
\varphi:(u,v,w)\mapsto (u,v)
$$
where $w=-\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}\,.$ Expressed in these coordinates $u,v$ the map $f$
is
$$
(f\circ\varphi^{-1})(u,v)\mapsto \left(\frac u{1+\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}},\frac v{1+\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}}\right)\,.
$$
This leads to the pullbacks
\begin{align}
f^*dx&=\frac {du}{1+\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}}+\frac1{\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}}\frac {u^2\,du+uv\,dv}{\big(1+\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}\big)^2}\,,\\[2mm]
f^*dy&=\frac {dv}{1+\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}}+\frac1{\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}}\frac {uv\,du+v^2\,dv}{\big(1+\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}\big)^2}\,.
\end{align}

The same expressions we could have obtained by replacing
$dw$ by $\frac{u\,du+v\,dv}{\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}}$ in the $\mathbb R^3$ case above as it must be.

In polar coordinates
\begin{align}
u&=\cos\varphi\sin\theta\,,&v&=\sin\varphi\sin\theta\,,&w&=\cos\theta
\end{align}
we get a chart $\varphi$ that leads to
$$
(f\circ\varphi^{-1})(\varphi,\theta)\mapsto\left(\frac{\cos\varphi\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta},\frac{\sin\varphi\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta}\right)
$$
and to the pullbacks
\begin{align}
f^*dx&=-\frac{-\sin\varphi\sin\theta\,d\varphi+\cos\varphi\cos\theta\,d\theta}{1-\cos\theta}+\frac{\cos\varphi\sin^2\theta\,d\theta}{(1-\cos\theta)^2}\,,\\[2mm]
f^*dy&=-\frac{\cos\varphi\sin\theta\,d\varphi+\sin\varphi\cos\theta\,d\theta}{1-\cos\theta}+\frac{\sin\varphi\sin^2\theta\,d\theta}{(1-\cos\theta)^2}\,.
\end{align}


